# AppSync BatchGet Filtered Returns Limit Error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

#### Background

We're using AWS AppSync with attached DynamoDB data sources. We've run into a really perplexing situation when attempting to filter queries before returning batch results to our clients. The goal is to filter our results based on substrings contained in the key being filtered.

Our DynamoDB has a composite key that looks like this:

```
nameGroup: String // partition key; the first letter of the sort key value
name: String // sort key; the full name of the object
Attributes:
    locationID: String // a three-character string
    officialName: String // a more formal name
    ... etc.
```

For example:

```
nameGroup: A
name: Australia
locationID: AUS
officialName: Australia
... etc.
```

And here you'll find our request resolver:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "nameGroup-locationID-index",
    "query" : {
        ## Query based off of first letter of supplied String **
        "expression" : "nameGroup = :nameGroup",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":nameGroup" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(${ctx.args.filter.substring(0,1)})
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
        ## Filter query list with 'contains' expression **
        "expression" : "contains(#name, :name)",
        "expressionNames" : {
            "#name" : "name"
        },
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":name" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(${ctx.args.filter})
        }
    },
    ## Add 'limit' and 'nextToken' arguments to implement pagination **
    "limit": $util.defaultIfNull(${ctx.args.count}, 3),
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank(${ctx.args.nextToken}, null))
}
```

And our response resolver:

```
{
    ## Change default return field (items) to appropriate PaginatedCountries field **
    "countryRefs": $util.toJson($ctx.result.items),
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($context.result.nextToken, null))
}
```

#### The Problem

When we query with something like this:

```
getCountryList(filter: $filter) {
    countryRefs {
        name
        locationID
        officialName
    }
    nextToken
}
```

where the `filter` var changes in value as the user inputs characters — e.g., `$filter = A`, then `$filter = Au`, then `$filter = Aus`, etc. — we get very strange returns. In almost all cases, we seem to get something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getCountryList": {
            "countryRefs": [],
            "nextToken": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJ0b2..." // a very long string token
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, if we use `nextToken` we'll find the results we're looking for in either the second or third page of results:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getCountryList": {
            "countryRefs": [
                {
                    "locationID": "AUS",
                    "name": "Australia"
                },
                {
                    "locationID": "AUT",
                    "name": "Austria"
                }
            ],
            "nextToken": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJ0b2..." // another very long string token
        }
    }
}
```

#### Hypothesis

We've spent way too many hours thinking this was an issue with our filter expression (like could `contains` be the issue or maybe `begins_with` is the problem?). What we've noticed, though, is that if we change the `limit` (either the default `3` or through a client-provided `count`) to something generally *larger than* the expected size of the array of elements that would be returned in our query — that is, before the filter expression is applied to the results — the issue doesn't seem to exist.

For example, using `filter: 'Au'`, if we set the default limit to `200` instead of `3`, we get exactly what we should be getting (there are only two country names beginning with 'Au')!

My question is this: why is the `limit` apparently returning what I'm going to call arrays with "hidden" values? My guess is that the total return size is being returned with a bunch of empty values except for indices where filter matches are found. Either way, why aren't we getting returns in the expected way? Why is `limit` filtering more than just the number of returns here — i.e., the way returns are actually structured?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. What happens is that with DynamoDb, a filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned. So basically it might be that your query returned results that were not relevant from the filter expression perspective and were subsequently filtered out and you get next tokens to retrieve more results. After following a couple of next tokens, you retrieve relevant results that you can display to the user.

From the DynamoDb perspective, a single Scan operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the limit parameter which in your case is set to 3) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression. When you set it to 200 that's why you get relevant results since you probably get all the existing countries and the filter expression is applied.

Comment: I understand how and when the filter expression is applied to Query, but what I'm not understanding is how or why this should be expected behavior. Why return an empty `[]` if "relevant" results -- meaning any results, at all -- do, in fact, exist? Why wouldn't the response resolver condense the resulting filtered Query results into a new array of values that show up to the limit maximum? I guess what I'm asking is why you would want to return empty arrays on simple filters and, more importantly, how can I condense the resulting filter further before returning to the client?

Comment: This is based on how DynamoDb data is stored. Data is sent to a partition based on a partition key and a sort key further sorts the data inside the partition key. The operation that's being called is a scan which goes through the data the only way it can based on the storage, going through the data for that partition key/sort key and retrieving that data after it scanned a certain amount of data. Filters are applied before returning the scanned data and you get a continuation token to retrieve more results.

Comment: That makes sense if the operation is, indeed, a Scan; however, I’m explicitly performing a Query (see the ‘operation’ field in my Request VTL Resolver above). Are Query and Scan effectively operating similarly in this context then?

Comment: That's pretty much the same in the context of FilterExpression. Check out the Query docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Comment: Hmmm... very interesting. Thanks for the info! Any suggestions on how to get the desired result — I.e., all objects whose name key I’m filtering on containing some provided substring without the empty array returns and sized appropriately to the default ‘limit’?

Comment: Before the filter is applied, the partition key and sort key are applied first. In your use-case, you hit sparse data after the partition key and sort key, not much data is of your interest. If your use case permits, you could incorporate part of the filter expression into the partition keys or sort keys so that you hit more relevant data straight away.